# Tinkerpop API does not use mixed elasticsearch index while retrieving data from titan

Tags: indexing, titan, mixed, tinkerpop3

Tinkerpop API does not use mixed elasticsearch index while retrieving data from titan. Though if we directly use titan API it does use mixed elasticsearch index.

e.g. 
I have created a mixed index on name.

When we use tinkerpop API : `graph.iterator().V().has("name", "Apple")`, 
it does not use mixed index on "name" and gives a warning log 'Query requires iterating over all vertices'.

With titan API it works fine and uses the mixed index on "name" as given below

```
titanGraph.query().has("name", "Apple").vertices()
```

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Can you post the code where you created the mixed index? Did you create the vertex property `name` and the mixed index in the same schema management transaction?

Comment: Have you tried `graph.traversal().V().has("name", "Apple")`?

Answer (score 2):

This was cross-posted on the [TinkerPop mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/GBfL-d-j_f0/1q9Am5IvBAAJ)

First off, if you're doing exact string matches, it seems like a [composite index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_index) would do fine.

You should review the [Titan docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html) in Chapter 20. Index Parameters and Full-Text Search. When you `addKey(name)` without a mapping parameter, the mixed index for a String key will default to a full-text search -- `addKey(name, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter())`. There are a lot of gotchas listed in the documentation to consider with full-text search:

- the string is tokenized into a bag of words which allows the user to efficiently query for all matches that contain one or multiple words.
- Titan’s default tokenization splits the string on non-alphanumeric characters and removes any tokens with less than 2 characters.
- only full-text search predicates are supported in graph queries by the indexing backend. [`textContains`, `textContainsPrefix`, `textContainsRegex`]
- Full-text search is case-insensitive.

Your query is trying to do an equals comparison, so perhaps `Mapping.STRING` or `Mapping.TEXTSTRING` would be more appropriate.

I created a couple gists to compare the different versions. You can cut and paste these examples in to the Gremlin Console.

Titan 0.5.4 https://gist.github.com/pluradj/ff1e1b1bcea0753adbb1

Titan 1.0.0 https://gist.github.com/pluradj/9bf96f8eae9fa24f3d61

Note that this behavior hasn't changed between Titan 0.5.4 and 1.0.0, so I'm not sure why your example worked previously.

Comment: Using Mapping.STRING makes the property as not_analyzed in elastic search and we loose the case insensitivity in elasticsearch on the property. Before marking the property with Mapping.STRING, it allowed us to do a case insensitive search directly at least in elasticsearch cluster.         By the way how to do a contains search in graph using tinkerpop API on the property with Mapping.TEXT. Any example would help.

Comment: You did not mention case insensitivity as a requirement in your original question. Using `Mapping.TEXT` with a `.has('name', textContains('apple'))` predicate should work then. Please refer to the Titan 1.0.0 gist I linked previously. It has examples of all text predicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with mixed ES indexes. There is a delay in data getting updated/created in ES. So if a record is created and then immediately queried by a mixed index key, we don't get it back. Please refer [Titan 1.0[Berkeley+ES] - Delayed update of ES index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686620/titan-1-0berkeleyes-delayed-update-of-es-index)