# Titan 1.0[Berkeley+ES] - Delayed update of ES index

Tags: elasticsearch, transactions, titan, tinkerpop3

Titan 1.0 [Berkeley+ Remote Elastic Search] 
we are using this combination of Titan. Following is the properties file -

```
storage.backend=berkeleyje
storage.directory=D:/other-projects/graph-db/titan/enron-tk3/db/berkeley
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.index-name=akshayatitan
index.search.hostname=localhost
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode=false
```

We are only using Mixed Index.
Now we add a node with few properties through Java code and then fetch it.

We query by a property on which a mixed index is created.
When we query the node back by the key (one which mixed index is created) , we don't get the node immediately. However it get available after a delay.
What are we doing wrong ? Or is this delayed update of ES instance is expected?
Here is the Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GraphTest test = new GraphTest();
    test.init();
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    String emailId = "emailId" + System.nanoTime();
    test.createNode(emailId);
    System.out.println("Create " + emailId);
    System.out.println("First time " + test.getNode(emailId));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("After a delay of 2 sec " + test.getNode(emailId));
}

public void createNode(String emailid) {
    Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex("person");
    vertex.property("emailId", emailid);
    vertex.property("firstName", "First Name");
    vertex.property("lastName", "Last Name");
    vertex.property("address", "Address");
    vertex.property("hometown", "Noida");
    vertex.property("city", "Noida");
    vertex.property("spousename", "Preeti");

    graph.tx().commit();

}

public Object getNode(String emailId) {
    Vertex vert = null;
    String reString = null;
    try {
        vert = graph.traversal().V().has("emailId", emailId).next();
        reString = vert.value("emailId");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        graph.tx().close();
    }

    return reString;
}
```

The code to create index is -

```
    private void createMixedIndexForVertexProperty(String indexName, String propertyKeyName, Class<?> propertyType) {

    TitanManagement mgmt = ((TitanGraph) graph).openManagement();
    try {
        PropertyKey propertyKey = makePropertyKey(propertyKeyName, propertyType, mgmt);
        TitanGraphIndex graphIndex = mgmt.getGraphIndex(indexName);
        if (graphIndex == null) {
            graphIndex = mgmt.buildIndex(indexName, Vertex.class)
                    .addKey(propertyKey, Parameter.of("mapping", Mapping.STRING)).buildMixedIndex("search");
        } else {
            mgmt.addIndexKey(graphIndex, propertyKey);
        }
        mgmt.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mgmt.rollback();
    } finally {
    }

}

public PropertyKey makePropertyKey(String propertyKeyName, Class<?> propertyType, TitanManagement mgmt) {

    PropertyKey propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey(propertyKeyName);
    if (propertyKey == null) {
        propertyKey = mgmt.makePropertyKey(propertyKeyName).dataType(String.class).make();
    }
    return propertyKey;
}

public void init() throws Exception {
    graph = TitanFactory
            .open(new PropertiesConfiguration(new File("src/test/resources/titan-berkeleydb-es.properties")));
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "emailId", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "firstName", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "lastName", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "address", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "hometown", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "city", String.class);
    createMixedIndexForVertexProperty("personnode", "spousename", String.class);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before on the [Titan mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/JFNthKyiBRM/bEqHTuumCwAJ).

> note that there's a latency in ES indexing (`index.refresh_interval`).
>   You can't update / insert a value and immediately query it. Wait at
>   least 1 second before you query the value, otherwise the result may be
>   empty.

You should also read up on the Elasticsearch documentation ([modifying your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/_modifying_your_data.html) and [near real-time search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html)) on the indexing behavior:

> Elasticsearch provides data manipulation and search capabilities in
>   near real time. By default, you can expect a one second delay (refresh
>   interval) from the time you index/update/delete your data until the
>   time that it appears in your search results. This is an important
>   distinction from other platforms like SQL wherein data is immediately
>   available after a transaction is completed.
>
> **CAUTION** The `refresh_interval` expects a duration such as `1s` (1 second) or `2m` (2
>   minutes). An absolute number like `1` means 1 millisecond--a sure way to
>   bring your cluster to its knees.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I tried to search through but didn't get relevant information. Your response is spot on.

Comment: Here is the use that we want to achieve because of which we had to query the record in real time.

Comment: We want to search the graph data so need NGRAM support for partial search. Unfortunately we could not achieve this with default ES index (Titan). The support for custom index creation is not enough. So we ended up creating another index (ngram) with desired configuration. 
Now we have a job to keep them in sync, so a need to keep updating the data from titan index to ngram index.  We also wanted to keep the ids of these records same. So as and when a record is updated, we query titan index, get the data and copy it over to ngram with same index id.

Comment: It was to keep the ids in sync that we had to query from titan in real time, resulting in this issue. However we found that ES id =LongEncoding.encode(vertex id)

This approach of two data sources is a problem, however with limited support for index customization (from what we gathered so far), it is difficult. I think this should be a good use case and an enhancement could be provided.